# Fallout-style homework game

Tags: python, beginner, game, homework, python-2.x

I've been going through LPHW (learn Python the hard way) lessons and I am now at exercise No36 where I have to create a similar game.

Could you please review it and point out beginner mistakes?

```
from sys import exit

inventory = []
ground = ['Bones', "Commander's Key", 'Security Code', 'Shipment Report']

turrets_active = True
rats_hungry = True
hatch_active = True

def check_inventory(inv):
    print 
    print ">The contents of your inventory are:"
    if len(inv) > 0:
        for counter, content in enumerate(inv):
            # This will look like " 0 . Bones " and then " 1 . Security Code " etc
            print ">", counter, ".", content
    else:
        print
        print ">Your inventory is empty"

def report_in_inventory():
    if 'Shipment Report' in inventory:
        print
        print "You map the coordinates from the report to your PIP-BOY"
        print "Fort Everlast awaits!"
        print "CONGRATULATIONS! YOU COMPLETED THE GAME!"
    else:
        print
        print "You wander the desert for the rest the day..."
        exit("But deathclaws get you near Broken Hills...")

def take_item(item):
    if item in ground:
        inventory.append(item)
        print
        print ">", item, "taken."
        ground.remove(item)
    else:
        print
        print ">You check same spots all over again"
        print ">but there is nothing to be found"
        print

def surroundings_text():
    print """
    You find yourself in a valley surrounded by the mountains.
    You are in a field of the old pre-war satellite dishes
    that glare at you with their eyeless faces.
    In front of you is an entrance to the Underground Control Complex
    that was used to operate the satellite array.
    By looks of it the door is guarded by automated Gatling turrets
    that will tear you to shreds.
    On your right you see a small passage between the mountains
    On your left there is an old maintenance hatch surrounded by a fence.
    """
    surroundings()

def surroundings():
    print
    print "1. Use Underground Control Complex entrance"
    print "2. Check the old maintenance hatch"
    print "3. Check the small passage"
    print "4. Go back to the desert. What awaits you there?"
    print "5. See if you can find something useful around..."
    print "6. Check your inventory."
    print

    choice = raw_input(">What do you do? ")

    if choice == "1" and turrets_active:
        print
        print "Last thing you hear is a 'swoosh' of the turrets"
        exit("You are torn to shreds. Your remains later eaten by rats")
    elif choice == "1" and turrets_active == False:
        me_text()
    elif choice == "2" and hatch_active:

        if 'Bones' in inventory:
            print "You hop over the fence and try the hatch."
            print "It's rusted shut but you are strong enough to open it."
            print
            print "You get engulfed by the smell from the tunnels below"
            print "but you decide to descend and check it out anyway."
            mt_text()
        else:
            print
            print "You should probably check the surroundings first"
            surroundings()

    elif choice == "2" and hatch_active == False:
        print "The hatch is a toast after your last visit. You turn back"
        surroundings()
    elif choice == "3":
        print "You squeeze through the narrow passage..."
        ts_text()
    elif choice == "4":
        report_in_inventory()
    elif choice == "5":
        print
        print "You roam around the dishes for awhile staying as far away"
        print "as possible from the Gatling turrets near the Main Entrance.."
        print "You think you see something behind one of the bigger rocks"
        print "and you go check it out..."
        take_item('Bones')
        surroundings()
        print
    elif choice == "6":
        check_inventory(inventory)
        surroundings()
    else:
        print
        print "Please use numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
        surroundings()

def mt_text():
    print """
    When you reach the bottom you see huge pack of molerats
    that will surely tear you to shreds...
    Not so far from the place where the pack is nested you see
    a glimmering light.
    But you have to deal with those molerats first, don't you?
    Luckily you found those bones on the surface...
    """
    maintenance_tunnels()

def maintenance_tunnels():
    global rats_hungry
    global hatch_active

    print 
    print "1. Attack the molerats with largest bone you found on the surface"
    print "2. Go towards the light"
    print "3. Use the bones as bait."
    print "4. Go back to the surface"
    print "5. Check your inventory"
    print

    choice = raw_input(">What do you do? ")

    if choice == "1" and rats_hungry:
        print
        print "You run towards the molerats and try to hit the largest one!"
        print "You miss!"
        print "Molerats jump on you and tear you to shreds"
        exit("Last thing you remember is the crunch of your testicles")
    elif choice == "2" and rats_hungry:
        print
        print "You try to sneak around the molerat pack"
        print "But the largest rat spots you and attacks with whole horde."
        exit("Last thing you remember is the crunch of your testicles")
    elif choice == "2" and rats_hungry == False:
        print
        print "You silently move out of the alcove you've been hiding in"
        print "and run towards the light at the end of the tunnel..."
        print "While you get closer and closer you hear the molerats"
        print "finishing their meal and crunching on something metallic."
        print "Few seconds later the ladder that you used to get down"
        print "collapses along with the ceiling of the tunnel."

        hatch_active = False

        print
        print "You reach the door handle under the glimmering light"
        print "just in time to save your life. The door has an ID on it:"
        print "Array Control Center. AUTHORIZED PERSONNEL ONLY"
        print "You enter the unknown..."
        uc_text()
    elif choice == "3" and rats_hungry:
        print
        print "You throw the bones behind you and hide in the nearest alcove."
        inventory.remove('Bones')
        rats_hungry = False
        maintenance_tunnels()
    elif choice == "3" and rats_hungry == False:
        print
        print "You don't have anything else to feed the rats."
        print "You'd better hurry out of your hiding place..."
        maintenance_tunnels()
    elif choice == "4" and rats_hungry:
        print
        print "You climb back to the surface"
        surroundings()
    elif choice == "4" and rats_hungry == False:
        print
        print "Molerats now block your way back. It's too late"
        maintenance_tunnels()
    elif choice == "5":
        check_inventory(inventory)
        maintenance_tunnels()
    else:
        print
        print "Please use numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
        maintenance_tunnels()

def uc_text():
    print"""
    You light up your old lantern and find yourself in a catacomb of
    corridors and doors. Some of the corridors are collapsed and
    some doors are blocked. The overall view is very much
    depressing. You roam this shallow installation until you think
    that it's time to decide which one of the more or less working
    doors to check...
    """
    underground_complex()

def underground_complex():
    print 
    print "1. Check the Armory door"
    print "2. Check the Commander's Quarters door"
    print "3. Check the TEST SITE Terrace door"
    print "4. Check Main Entrance door"
    print "5. See if you can find something useful around..."
    print "6. Check your inventory."
    print

    choice = raw_input(">What do you do? ")

    if choice == "1":

        if 'Security Code' in inventory:
            print
            print "You input the security code into the slowly blinking pad."
            print "The yellow light above the door starts flashing"
            print "and it slowly opens with a shrieking creak."
            armory_text()
        else:
            print
            print "You see the code pad on the right from the door"
            print "but there is no code scratched or written anywhere nearby."
            print "You should probably check around the Complex thoroughly..."
            underground_complex()

    elif choice == "2":

        if "Commander's Key" in inventory:
            print
            print "You slide the keycard into the socket. Something clicks"
            print "and the door silently unlocks. Judging by the door sound"
            print "there is a chance that nobody's been here after the war..."
            cq_text()
        else:
            print
            print "The door is locked but you see a keycard slot."
            print "You wonder if you should check around the Complex..."
            print "If this place hasn't been looted you can probably"
            print "find that keycard on one of the bodies around."
            underground_complex()

    elif choice == "3":
        print
        print "The door is rusted shut and cannot be opened"
        underground_complex()
    elif choice == "4":
        print
        print "You hit the switch on a console and a large round door"
        print "slowly rolls aside..."
        me_text()
    elif choice == "5":
        print
        print "As you rummage around the various rooms and cabinets you find"
        print "a small piece of fragile paper with some numbers on it."
        print "What would that be? A code?"
        take_item('Security Code')
        underground_complex()
    elif choice == "6":
        check_inventory(inventory)
        underground_complex()
    else:
        print
        print "Please use numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
        underground_complex()

def armory_text():
    print """
    As you enter the Armory you notice that all the weapon lockers are
    (of course) already cleaned out.
    In the corner you see a skeleton dressed in high-ranking uniform.
    Maybe he was a commander?
    """
    armory()

def armory():
    print 
    print "1. See if you can find something useful on the skeleton..."
    print "2. Go back."
    print "3. Check your inventory."
    print

    choice = raw_input(">What do you do? ")

    if choice == "1":
        print
        print "You approach the skeleton and notice that its skull is blown"
        print "to pieces. The guy probably shot himself. Poor fella..."
        print "As you rummage through his pockets you find a keycard."
        print "Better check those other doors in the Complex to see"
        print "where this can be applied..."
        take_item("Commander's Key")
        armory()
    elif choice == "2":
        print
        print "You turn around and go back to the Underground Complex"
        underground_complex()
    elif choice == "3":
        check_inventory(inventory)
        armory()
    else:
        print
        print "Please use numbers 1, 2, 3"
        armory()

def ts_text():
    print """
    Far on the horizon you see a large crater formed by a nuclear blast.
    It is black as night and you feel goosebumps running all over your neck. 
    So many lives taken during this war. War never changes...
    On your left you notice a small terrace overlooking the mountains 
    and the valley below.
    Can it be another entrance to the Complex? Better watch for turrets."
    """
    test_site()

def test_site():
    print 
    print "1. Approach the terrace."
    print "2. See if you can find something useful around..."
    print "3. Go back to Satellite array."
    print "4. Check your inventory."
    print

    choice = raw_input(">What do you do? ")

    if choice == "1" and turrets_active:
        print
        print "As you approach the terrace you see the Gatling Turrets"
        print "slowly rising from the mountain slopes..."
        print "The moment you understand that it is too late to run"
        exit("you are torn to shreds by their fire.")
    elif choice == "1" and not turrets_active:
        print
        print "You spent a few minutes climbing but finally reach the terrace."
        print "The view to the valley is magnificent but depressing"
        print "at the same time. Semi-destroyed satellite array to your right"
        print "and nuclear test site that lays in front of your eyes remind"
        print "of the war that destroyed us all..."
        print "You try the door but its rusted shut so you climb back down."
        test_site()
    elif choice == "2":
        take_item("None")
        test_site()
    elif choice == "3":
        print
        print "You turn around and go back to the Satellite Array"
        surroundings()
    elif choice == "4":
        check_inventory(inventory)
        test_site()
    else:
        print
        print "Please use numbers 1, 2, 3"
        test_site()

def cq_text():
    print """
    As you enter the room you feel a certain amount of homesickness swept
    over you. Dusty but yet neatly placed furniture reminds you of your
    hometown of Arroyo that you left behind so long ago. 
    A small green light slowly blinking on a miraculously working console
    catches your attention...
    """
    commander_quarters()

def commander_quarters():
    print 
    print "1. Check the console"
    print "2. Go back."
    print "3. Check your inventory."
    print

    choice = raw_input(">What do you do? ")

    if choice == "1":
        print
        print "You check the console and print out a single piece of"
        print "information that is available. Everything else (whatever that"
        print "was) is deleted wiped clean off the tape-drive."

        take_item("Shipment Report")

        print
        print "When you look at what came out of the old matrix printer"
        print "you see a shipment report of a crate of highly valuable"
        print "Plasma Rifles to a place yet unknown to you - Fort Everlast."
        print
        commander_quarters()
    elif choice == "2":
        print
        print "You turn around and go back to the Underground Complex"
        underground_complex()
    elif choice == "3":
        check_inventory(inventory)
        commander_quarters()
    else:
        print
        print "Please use numbers 1, 2, 3"
        commander_quarters()

def me_text():
    print """
    You find yourself at the main entrance to the
    Underground Complex. You see a probably working terminal
    behind one of the Gatling Turrets and a console
    near the large round door leading inside.
    """
    main_entrance()

def main_entrance():
    global turrets_active

    print 
    print "1. Check the Terminal"
    print "2. Go to satellite array."
    print "3. Go to Underground Complex."
    print "4. Check your inventory."
    print

    choice = raw_input(">What do you do? ")

    if choice == "1" and turrets_active:
        print
        print "You approach the blinking terminal and hit the red button."
        print "Loud shriek fills the air but fells silent after a while."
        print "The lonely message pops on the screen."
        print "TURRETS DEACTIVATED. PLEASE PUT HUMAN SENTRIES ON GUARD"

        turrets_active = False

        main_entrance()
    elif choice == "1" and not turrets_active:
        print
        print "The terminal seems dead. There is nothing for you here."
        main_entrance()
    elif choice == "2" and turrets_active:
        print
        print "As you move down the slope towards the satellite array"
        print "you hear a smooth 'whoosh'. Before you realize it is too late"
        exit("and you are torn to shreds by Gatling Turrets.")
    elif choice == "2" and not turrets_active:
        print
        print "You slide down the slope towards the satellite array."
        surroundings()
    elif choice == "3":
        print
        print "You hit the switch on a console and a large round door"
        print "slowly rolls aside..."
        underground_complex()
    elif choice == "4":
        check_inventory(inventory)
        main_entrance()
    else:
        print
        print "Please use numbers 1, 2, 3, 4"
        main_entrance()

print
surroundings_text()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be inclined to reduce some of the duplication using dictionaries and functions, if not classes.

For example, you repeatedly take user input from defined choices, which could all be done by:

```
def get_input(choices):
    for choice in sorted(choices):
        print("{0}. {1}".format(choice, choices[choice]))
    while True:
        try:
            ui = int(raw_input("Choose an action: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number.")
        else:
            if ui in choices:
                return ui
            print("Not a valid action.")
```

You can then use this function as:

```
action = get_input({1: "See if you can find something useful on the skeleton...",
                    2: "Go back.",
                    3: "Check your inventory."})
```

And guarantee a valid choice in the response. Each set of choices is now defined by a simple dictionary and the validation is handled in one place.

You could also hold the definitions of what to do for each choice in a dictionary, rather than the `if: elif:` blocks, although you will need to think about how to represent your choices' inventory items needed or global state (e.g. turrets active).

Similarly, you can handle moving around your world by having each choice return the next room to go to, then store all room functions in a dictionary:

```
rooms = {"tower": enter_tower, "bunker": enter_bunker, ...}
```

You could then finish by returning `None`, and have an overall game loop:

```
room = "tower" # first room 
while room is not None: # game loop
    room = rooms[room]() # call function and get next room
print("Game over.") # end of the game
```

This avoids your current recursive calling.

Finally, the `global` is a bad sign. Instead, you could have a `World` object or dictionary that holds this state:

```
world = {"rats hungry": True, "turrets active": False,
         "ground" ["bones", "security code", ...], 
         "inventory": [], ...}
```

and pass it around explicitly:

```
room = rooms[room](world)
```

Comment: Thank you for going through my wall of text. Im fairly new to python but what you are saying makes perfect sense. I will rework it and post an update as soon as I get to it. Thank you!